# SwiftUI NavigationView not remember the state

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having following trouble using NavigationView in SwiftUI.

I have a NavigationView embed in a TabView as follow:

```swift
var body: some View {
   TabView {
      NavigationView {
         View1()
      }
         .tabItem { Text("View 1") }
         .tag(1)
      View2()
         .tabItem {Text("View 2") }
         .tag(2)
   }
}
```

On the first tab, I have push several views to the `NavigationView`, but when switch to the second tab and then switch back to the first tab, the `NavigationView` become `View1()` again, all pushed views are erased. Demonstrated as bellow:

[image: Step By Step]

Expected behaviour is when switching to the first tab, the Payment view is showed instead of HomePage.

Is there anyway to put the state of NavigationView to an external `@EnvironmentObject`, for example, so that the state of `NavigationView` remain the same after switching.

Comment: Can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772137/tabview-resets-navigation-stack-when-switching-tabs

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is a pretty easy way of using an state with an NavigationLink.
There is a optional property isActive you give an @Binding variable, which also can be from an external Environment object using a @Published property inside the observable object.
In Case you want to learn a bit more about SwiftUI NavigationView including the Navigation Link consider checking out this awesome [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA6Jo6YnL9g&t=837s) by Paul Hudson. It personally helped me a lot.