# How to maintain scroll position in a SwiftUI TabView

Tags: swiftui, tabview

Using a `ScrollView` inside a `TabView` I've noticed that the ScrollView does not maintain it's scroll position when I move back an forth between tabs. How do I change the below example to get the ScrollView to maintain it's scroll position?

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Text("Line 2")
                Text("Line 3")
                Text("Line 4")
                Text("Line 5")
                Text("Line 6")
                Text("Line 7")
                Text("Line 8")
                Text("Line 9")
                Text("Line 10")
            }
        }.font(.system(size: 80, weight: .bold))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                }.tag(0)

            Text("Out")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "cloud")
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find helpful my customisation of `ScrollView` in [How to make a SwiftUI List scroll automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258846/how-to-make-a-swiftui-list-scroll-automatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## November 2020 update

`TabView` will now maintain scroll position in tabs when moving in between tabs, so the approaches in the  answers to my original question are no longer necessary.

Comment: TabView certainly keeps the scroll position when programatically changing the `selection` binding but when using the swipe gesture to change between tabs, if there are 4 or more tabs the scroll position is reset eventually. I reported the bug and also created this [sample test project](https://github.com/yannxou/TabViewLostScrollPosition) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately this is simply not possible with built-in components given the current limitations of SwiftUI (iOS 13.x/Xcode 11.x).

Two reasons:

1. SwiftUI completely disposes of your View when you switch away from the tab.  This is why your scroll position is lost.  It's not like UIKit where you have a bunch of offscreen UIViewControllers.
2. There is no `ScrollView` equivalent of `UIScrollView.contentOffset`.  That means you can't save your scroll state somewhere and restore it when the user returns to the tab.

Your easiest route is probably going to be using a `UITabBarController` filled with `UIHostingController`s.  That way you won't lose the state of each tab as users move between them.

Otherwise, you could create a custom tab container, and *modify the opacity* of each tab yourself (as opposed to conditionally including them in the hierarchy, which is what causes your problem currently).

```swift
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    self.tab1Content.opacity(self.currentTab == .tab1 ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    self.tab2Content.opacity(self.currentTab == .tab2 ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    self.tab3Content.opacity(self.currentTab == .tab3 ? 1.0 : 0.0)
  }
}
```

I've used this technique when I wanted to keep a `WKWebView` from completely reloading every time a user briefly tabbed away.

**I would recommend the first technique**.  Especially if this is your app's main navigation.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using your first option, which is more fleshed out in this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58164937/98374 Given your answer I was able to locate it

Answer (score 1):

This answer is posted as a complement to the solution @oivvio linked in the answer from @arsenius, about how to use a `UITabController` filled with `UIHostingController`s.

The answer in the link has one issue: if the children views have external SwiftUI dependencies, those children will not be updated. This is fine for most cases where children views only have internal states. However, if you are like me, a React developer who enjoys a global Redux system, you will be in trouble.

In order to resolve the issue, the key is to update `rootView` for each `UIHostingController` every time when `updateUIViewController` is called. My code also avoids creating unnecessary `UIView` or `UIViewControllers`: they are not that expensive to create if you do not add them to the view hierarchy, but still, the less waste the better.

**Warning**: the code does not support a dynamic tab view list. To support that correctly, we would like to identify each child tab view and do an array diff to add, order, or remove them correctly. That can be done in principle but goes beyond my need.

We first need a `TabItem`. It is made this way for the controller to grab all the information, without creating any `UITabBarItem`:

```swift
struct XNTabItem: View {
    let title: String
    let image: UIImage?
    let body: AnyView

    public init<Content: View>(title: String, image: UIImage?, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.body = AnyView(content())
    }
}
```

We then have the controller:

```swift
struct XNTabView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let tabItems: [XNTabItem]

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<XNTabView>) -> UITabBarController {
        let rootController = UITabBarController()
        rootController.viewControllers = tabItems.map {
            let host = UIHostingController(rootView: $0.body)
            host.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: $0.title, image: $0.image, selectedImage: $0.image)
            return host
        }
        return rootController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ rootController: UITabBarController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<XNTabView>) {
        let children = rootController.viewControllers as! [UIHostingController<AnyView>]
        for (newTab, host) in zip(self.tabItems, children) {
            host.rootView = newTab.body
            if host.tabBarItem.title != host.tabBarItem.title {
                host.tabBarItem.title = host.tabBarItem.title
            }
            if host.tabBarItem.image != host.tabBarItem.image {
                host.tabBarItem.image = host.tabBarItem.image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Children controllers are initialized in `makeUIViewController`. Whenever `updateUIViewController` is called, we update each children controller's root view. I did *not* do a comparison for `rootView` because I feel the same check would be done at the framework level, according to Apple's description about how views are updated. I might be wrong.

To use it is really simple. The below is partial code I grabbed from a mock project I am currently doing:

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allHouseInfo = HouseInfo.samples

    public func flipFavorite(for id: Int) {
        if let index = (allHouseInfo.firstIndex { $0.id == id }) {
            allHouseInfo[index].isFavorite.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct FavoritesView: View {
    let favorites: [HouseInfo]

    var body: some View {
        if favorites.count > 0 {
            return AnyView(ScrollView {
                ForEach(favorites) {
                    CardContent(info: $0)
                }
            })
        } else {
            return AnyView(Text("No Favorites"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    static let housingTabImage = UIImage(systemName: "house.fill")
    static let favoritesTabImage = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")

    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var favorites: [HouseInfo] {
        get { model.allHouseInfo.filter { $0.isFavorite } }
    }

    var body: some View {
        XNTabView(tabItems: [
            XNTabItem(title: "Housing", image: Self.housingTabImage) {
                NavigationView {
                    ScrollView {
                        ForEach(model.allHouseInfo) {
                            CardView(info: $0)
                                .padding(.vertical, 8)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        }
                    }.navigationBarTitle("Housing")
                }
            },
            XNTabItem(title: "Favorites", image: Self.favoritesTabImage) {
                NavigationView {
                    FavoritesView(favorites: favorites).navigationBarTitle("Favorites")
                }
            }
        ]).environmentObject(model)
    }
}
```

The state is lifted to a root level as `Model` and it carries mutation helpers. In the `CardContent` you could access the state and the helpers via an `EnvironmentObject`. The update would be done in the `Model` object, propagated to the `ContentView`, with our `XNTabView` notified and each of its `UIHostController` updated.

EDITs:

- It turns out that `.environmentObject` can be put at the top level.